# How to convert RowMatrix to RDD[vector]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, pca

The matrix is output from PCA, and I am using the results from PCA to make clustering .

```
val lData =  sqlContext.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
val vecData = lData.rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getInt(0),s.getAs[Seq[Double]](1):_*)).cache()
val mat = new RowMatrix(vecData)
val pc = mat.computePrincipalComponents(2)
val projected = mat.multiply(pc)
val numClusters =10
val numIteration = 10
val model=KMeans.train(vectors,numClusters,numIteration)
```

this error appears

> type mismatch;  found   : org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]

How to correct it?

Comment: I need to convert rowMatrix from pca to RDD[vector].

Comment: It's for SVD not pca.how to make like this.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30170898/1386551

Comment: thanks ,but this error appear not found: value vectors.def matrixToRDD(m: Matrix): RDD[Vector] = {
   val columns = m.toArray.grouped(m.numRows)
   val rows = columns.toSeq.transpose // Skip this if you want a column-major RDD.
   val vectors = rows.map(row => new DenseVector(row.toArray))
   sc.parallelize(vectors)
   
    }
    
  val numClusters =10
  val numIteration = 10
val model=KMeans.train(vectors,numClusters,numIteration)